# reading in a file with textscan and ignoring certain lines

Tags: matlab

I have an input file which has rows of integers like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I want to read in the file, I have used the textscan function for this kind of task before.
But there are a few lines in the data (at random positions) which contain double numbers, for example

```
<large number of integer lines>
0.12 12.44 65.34
<large number of integer lines>
```

When reading in the file, I want to **ignore** these lines. What's the best approach to do this? Can I tell textscan to ignore certain patterns?

Comment: why don't you read all data as integer, then remove the float values using `isfloat`

Comment: Can you give an example how to do that Nishant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't know the location and number of the lines with floats, and that you don't want lines such as `1.0 2.0 3.0` or `1 2 3.0` my idea would be to read the file line by line and not store lines which contain a `.` character.

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
nums = [];
line = fgetl(fid);
while line ~= -1 % #read until end of file
    if isempty(strfind(line, '.'))
        line = textscan(line, '%d %d %d');
        nums = [nums; line{:}];
    end
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

`nums` is the matrix containing your data.

Comment: I wonder if there's a nice non-iterative solution for this task.

Answer (score 4):

The formatSpec argument could be the one you're searching for:
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec

It terminates the reading, if the content does not match the given format. If you call textscan a second time with the same file, it has to start reading where it last terminated.

From linked site:

> If you resume a text scan of a file by calling textscan with the same
>   file identifier (fileID), then textscan automatically resumes reading
>   at the point where it terminated the last read.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to simply just read everything in as floats - use either `textscan` or if your data is all numeric `dlmread` or similar might be simpler.

Then just remove the lines you don't want:

```
data =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
    4.0000    5.0000    6.0000
    0.1200   12.4400   65.3400
    7.0000    8.0000    9.0000

 data(data(:,1)~=round(data(:,1)),:)=[]

data =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

If your later code requires that the type of your data matrix is non-float, use `uint8` or similar to convert at this point.

Comment: What if there's a line like `1.0 2.0 3.0` in the file?